Implementar Proto DataStore
Estoy tratando de añadir Proto DataStore a un proyecto android. Para ello, estoy siguiendo el codelab Cómo trabajar con Proto DataStore.
En la hoja 5, después de agregar las dependencias del plugin (com.google.protobuf) y las dependencias (datastore-core y protobuf-javalite), explica como configurar protobuf mediante el siguiente fragmento de código:
protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.14.0"
    }

    // Generates the java Protobuf-lite code for the Protobufs in this project. See
    // https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin#customizing-protobuf-compilation
    // for more information.
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.builtins {
                java {
                    option 'lite'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

El error que me aparece es: Unresolved reference: protobuf, que me da a pensar de que alguna dependencia no funciona, o me falta...
No se si el error se debe, a que las dependencias las he agregado de la siguiente forma:
Archivo libs.version.toml:
[libraries]
datastore-core = { group = "androidx.datastore", name = "datastore-core", version = "1.1.1" }
protobuf-javalite = { group = "com.google.protobuf", name = "protobuf-javalite", version = "3.18.0" }

[plugins]
protobuf = { id = "com.google.protobuf", version = "0.8.17" }

Archivo build.gradle.kts:
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.protobuf)
}

android {
    // xxx
}

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.14.0"
    }

    // Generates the java Protobuf-lite code for the Protobufs in this project. See
    // https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin#customizing-protobuf-compilation
    // for more information.
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.builtins {
                java {
                    option 'lite'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation(libs.datastore.core)
    implementation(libs.protobuf.javalite)
}

Una vez que lanzo el compilador, la lista de errores es la siguiente:

Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)
Unresolved reference: protoc
Unresolved reference: artifact
Unresolved reference: generateProtoTasks
Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch
Unresolved reference: option
Script compilation errors

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? ¿Acaso la documentación oficial es errónea?
Gracias de antemano

En dependencies te estás comiendo las comillas. Revisa aquí y usa la misma sintaxis, actualizando las versiones solamente.

Muchas gracias @A.Cedano, tu respuesta me ha servido para encontrar la solución

Por si algún usuario tiene el mismo problema. Dejo aquí la solución que me ha funcionado:
Archivo libs.version.toml:
[versions]
datastore = "1.1.1"
protobuf = "3.22.3"
plugin_protobuf = "0.9.4"

[libraries]
androidx-datastore-core = { group = "androidx.datastore", name = "datastore-core", version.ref = "datastore" }
protobuf-compiler = { group = "com.google.protobuf", name = "protoc", version.ref = "protobuf" }
protobuf-java = { group = "com.google.protobuf", name = "protobuf-java", version.ref = "protobuf" }
protobuf-kotlin = { group = "com.google.protobuf", name = "protobuf-kotlin", version.ref = "protobuf" }

[plugins]
protobuf = { id = "com.google.protobuf", version.ref = "plugin_protobuf" }

Archivo build.gradle.kts:
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.protobuf)
}

android {
    // xxx
}

dependencies {
    implementation(libs.androidx.datastore.core)
    implementation(libs.protobuf.compiler)
    implementation(libs.protobuf.java)
    implementation(libs.protobuf.kotlin)
}

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:${libs.versions.protobuf.get()}"
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().forEach { task ->
            task.builtins {
                create("java") {
                    option("lite")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Muchas gracias al usuario @A. Cedano, gracias a su comentario pude dar con la solución a la pregunta
